# CUDA Occupancy calculator: Occupancy per SM vs. Overall occupancy

Tags: c++, optimization, cuda

Probably a very basic question, but I so far didn't really understand the difference between the "Occupancy of each Multiprocessor" as shown in the blue box in the first image, and the "Multiprocessor Warp Occupancy" (Is that the overall Occupancy of my kernel?) which is plotted in the three graphs.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Occupancy of each multiprocessor is a function calculated with the number of active warps per multiprocessor (which depends on the active threads per multiprocessor). So basically, yes it's the overall of your occupancy. It's a good indicator of your occupany on each multiprocessor..

Comment: But why does the occupancy in the diagram have a maximum at 64% and not 100?

Comment: since the occupancy of each multiprocessor is 100%

Comment: No it's not the percentage, it's the number of warp used.